# How to switch between headphones and speakers without unplugging the headphones

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers, headphone-jack, audio-output

When i'm using Ubuntu 18,  I'm able to freely switch the audio output between my  plugged-in headphones (with a jack plug) and the PC speakers using PulseAudio, without unplugging the headphones .

I would like to be able to do the exact same thing on  Windows  10 (installed on the same computer) with a software switch  just like for Ubuntu.
Contrary to a lot of answers to similar questions, this doesn't seem to be a hardware-switch only setting, or else I would be unable to do that on linux.

In case this interests you, here's  the command i used to achieve that on ubuntu :

```
amixer -c 1 set 'Auto-Mute Mode' Disabled
```

Thanks for  your tips :)

edit :  Windows 10 pro 64 bit, version 1809 , OS build  17763.615

edit2: I only see Speakers (Realtek High definition audio)   when selecting the sound output device in the settings and in the taskbar

Comment: whats your windows 10 version ?

Comment: i updated my post  :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Open *Realtek HD Audio Manager* [`C:\Program Files\Realtek\Audio\HDA\RtkNGUI64.exe`]
2. Click on the settings 'cog' in the top right corner of RealTek HD Audio Manager and then select "Make front and rear output devices playback two different audio streams simultaneously".
3. Seamlessly switch between audio devices via the Taskbar or `Control Panel`.

Comment: There is no Multistreaming button!

Comment: Step 2 maybe - settings>option then select..

Answer (score 0):

After Windows 10 Anniversary update you should get the option to change the playback device simply by clicking on the speaker icon in the bottom right of the taskbar and then clicking on the upward arrow..if you don't see and arrow option, might be any driver issue.
https://www.techjunkie.com/windows-10-change-audio-playback-device/

Comment: This answer didn't work for the problem in the question. Plugging in a device in jack overwrite built-in speaker and only the external one appears in the list.

Comment: @MátéJuhász just because it didn't work for you doesn't mean  it will not work for others. 
It does not overwrite , check this link
https://www.pcgamer.com/how-to-easily-swap-between-headphones-and-speakers-in-windows-10/

Comment: I only see Speakers (Realtek High definition audio)   when selecting the output device while the headphones are plugged in  :(  thanks for trying though !

Comment: The PCGamer only worked for me after steps 1&2 of aniket's answer.  I think it may depends where the headphones are plugged in - front and back or both back etc